# limit rate of incomming connections to a nated host

Tags: iptables, nat, forwarding

I'm using this to rate limit and it works fine:

```
/usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m recent --rcheck --seconds 60 --hitcount 2 --name WWW -j LOG --log-prefix "WWW "

/usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 2 --name WWW -j DROP

/usr/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name WWW -j ACCEPT
```

The question is, I want to do the same, but the webserver is in another host. I'm natting all the traffic on port 80 to another server, lets say 192.168.1.20. How do I set the limit in the forward/nat/masquerade/whatever it's called?

Answer (score 1):

In your iptables rules, to redirect / masquerade to another IP address, you will use the NAT table, the PREROUTING chain and then the REDIRECT action. For example:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 [or whatever you're using as an interface] -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-destination [ip-address]
```

Add the timing and hitcount rules that you desire.

Comment: im not asking how to redirect traffic, i already do that, im asking how to rate limit the redirections to 2 per minute or something...

Comment: @kcinick Put the check in your `FORWARD` chain (including the new destination address on the rules), instead.

Comment: @ShaneMadden thanks, that work but there is a problem, it limit all the connections as if they come from the same ip, so if i connect 2 time the port is droped for everyone else, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I figured it out, i have to use the mangle table.